# Objects in Meteor Collection

Tags: javascript, meteor

I created the following function to be able to construct objects to store in a Meteor Collection and from there I can access its attributes. The function was created on server side.

```
  function tweet(uName, sName, uProfile, uTweet, uMedia) {
    this.userName = uName;
    this.screenName = sName;
    this.profileImage = uProfile;
    this.tweet = uTweet;
    this.mediaPic = uMedia;
  }
```

For testing purposes, I created a random tweet Object :

```
  var temp = new tweet (john, johnnyBoy, dog, 12, 14);
```

And when I logged it on console, it has been working fine. For example,

```
  console.log(temp.userName) //logged john
```

Now I inserted it into a collection with the following:

```
  Tweets.insert(temp);
```

And when I attempted to access the userName, keeps returning undefined.

```
 console.log(Tweets.find().userName);
```

Not sure why though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[find](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/find) returns a cursor. You need to call [findOne](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/findone) or [fetch](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/fetch) (on the cursor) to get a document. For example:

```
console.log(Tweets.findOne().userName);
console.log(Tweets.find().fetch()[0].userName);
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to query it like this

```
console.log(Tweets.findOne().userName);
```

.find() returns a cursor or a result set. If you want to get an actual item, use .findOne(). Or you could do the following:

`console.log(Tweets.find({}, {limit:1}).fetch()[0].userName); // errors out if no tweets in the collection`

Answer (score 0):

The function `collection.find([selector], [options])` returns a cursor, i.e. a reactive data source. That means that it does not immediately access the database or return documents. However, cursors provide the functions `fetch()`, `map()` and `forEach()`.

If you want to access a document of your `Tweets` collection, you need to use `Tweets.findOne([selector], [options])` or `Tweets.find([selector], [options]).fetch()[0]`.

Read more about [`collection.find([selector], [options])`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/find) and [`collection.findOne([selector], [options])`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/findone).